# In Activiti,get details of group who completed task from multiple candidate groups

Tags: activiti, bpmn

for example :- activiti:candidateGroups="group1,group2" here the usertask is viewable as pending tasks to both the groups but suppose group2 completed the task, how to get the detail that group2 is  the one who completed the task

Answer (score 0):

Great question.
Unfortunately as far as I know there is no way to determine which "role" a user completed a task on behalf of. In order to have this capability, the BPM system would need to support what are known as "swimlanes". Activiti and it's derivatives such as Camunda do not implement swimlanes.

Now, you should be able to implicitly "know" the users role for any given task as you know the role the task was assigned to.
For example, A loan application validation would be a "loan processor" role, no matter who actually completed it.
By correlating the necessary roles and those assigned to the actual user you should be able to determine the group under which they were acting.